# Поиск по многомерному массиву

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Есть простой сайт с новостями и категориями.

Допустим, пользователь захотел посмотреть все новости из категории world и перешел на страницу site.ru/category/world/

Как видно, в url страницы присутствует только название категории и нужно как-то получить её id, чтобы вывести все записи данной категории.

По идеи, достаточно сделать SELECT на поиск категории с названием wolrd и взять её id.

НО, лишний запрос делать не хочется, а т.к. вся информация о категориях у меня хранится в многомерном массиве, собственно возникает вопрос:

Как мне получить [id] из массива, где присутствует [url] => world ?

За место world, может быть любая другая категория, её название берется из $_GET['url_cat']

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Новости
            [url] => world
            [title] => Новости мира - Всё самое интересное!
            [description] => Описание категории новости!
            [keywords] => Ключевое слово, ключ, кей
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Политика
            [url] => politica
            [title] => Всё о политике
            [description] => Описание категории политика!
            [keywords] => Ключевое слово, ключ, кей
        )

)
```

Comment: А вы такой случай не рассматриваете, что база может вернуть все данные по категории найденной по слову wolrd, а не только ее id!? Или ваша СУБД настолько примитивна, что не может вернуть ни чего кроме id категории?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположил, что массив категорий лежит в переменной `$categories`, и что ищем ID категории `world`:

```
$id = array_column($categories, 'id', 'url')['world'];
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Как то так

```
function getID($AArray, $AURL) {
  foreach ($AArray as $item) {
    if (isset($item['url']) {
      // Достигли нужного уровня с данными
      if ($item['url'] === $AURL)
        return $item['id'];
    } else {
      // Иначе - вызываем себя рекурсивно для следующего уровня
      $res = getID($item, $AURL);
      // Если что-то нашли - выходим
      if (isset($res))
        return $res;
    }
  }
  // ничего не нашли
  return null;
}
```